# ffmpeg scaling with precise edges?

Tags: ffmpeg, images, scaling

i'd like to extract thumbnails from videos. the problem i'm running into is that the boundaries of the reduced images aren't clear due to edge effects in the scaling algorithm. here is a simple mire test pattern to show what i mean :
[ffmpeg-extracted image of test pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piLO4.png)
you can see here especially on the edges of the blue, red, and magenta fields that the borders have become indistinct due to blending from aliasing in the original video.

i want it to look more like this :
[same test pattern, idealised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFB55.png)

i've tried all of the different scaling algorithms ; `fast_bilinear` and `neighbor` appear to work best, w/`sws_dither` set to `none`. however, i still can't get the results i'm looking for. is there some sort of 'fuzz' factor one can specify, as with image magick, or some way to have ffmpeg change the colours of edges to the same as other near colours, in order to 'flatten' or reduce the number and complexity of colours in the final image ?

EXAMPLE COMMAND LINE :
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$infile" -vf "scale=w=100:h=-1:sws_dither=none:sws_flags=neighbor" -y $output`

Comment: This one of those tasks i'd just do in VLC.

Comment: ffmpeg is not really optimized for still image tasks: it will first calculate the video frame (with all associated problems) and then write the image. You'd better extract full res stills and then use an image app to reduce to thumbnails.

Comment: Which format are you extracting to?

Comment: thanks to all for the replies.
Tetsujin - unfortunately this needs to be scripted so treatment of the videos can be batched.
@Gyan - PNG.

Comment: Insert `format=rgb24` before the scale filter and check.